# Oracle client with SSL on Windows 10

Tags: java, c++, oracle, ssl, jdbc

We have applications both native (C++) and Java using Oracle client to connect to database. Our Native applications use OCI and our Java applications  use JDBC thin client.

When using SSL to connect to a remote database server from a Windows 10 machine, the connection takes alot of time to establish. This is true for both OCI and JDBC and it is the case only when the client is running on a Windows 10 computer. When the clients run on Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, connections are quick.

Does anyone have faced a similar problem or have an idea when the problem might be ?

Comment: What version of the Oracle client?  Windows 10 is pretty new.  Are you using older versions of the client that didn't exist when Windows 10 was available?  Have you tried using the most recent versions of the client and/or installing patchsets on the client?

Comment: For OCI, we are using version 11.2.0.3.0 of the instant client.

Comment: For JDBC, we are using version 10.2.0.5